# When to use codeigniter where() function and when get_where()

Tags: codeigniter

I've been reading docs regarding these 2 functions, but I still can't quite get the difference between these two.

I get it that `get_where` selects data from DB, but when should we use `where()` function and not `get_where()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### get_where()

There are tons of other ways to get data using CodeIgniter’s ActiveRecord implementation, but you also have full SQL queries if you need them:
Example:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('people', array('id' => 449587));
```

Ultimately, `get_where()` is the naive case, and certainly the most commonly-used in my code anyway — I can’t think of an another framework in any other language that enables you to be this productive with data with a single line of code.

```
get_where([$table = ''[, $where = NULL[, $limit = NULL[, $offset = NULL]]]])
```

Parameters:

- $table (mixed) – The table(s) to fetch data from; string or array
- $where (string) – The WHERE clause
- $limit (int) – The LIMIT clause
- $offset (int) – The OFFSET clause

This function is working as `get()` but with also allows the `WHERE` to be added directly.

> Identical to the `$this->db->get();` except that it permits you to add
>   a `where` clause in the second parameter, instead of using the
>   `db->where()` function.

#### where()

This function enables you to set WHERE clauses in your query.

You can also add where clauses, sort conditions and so forth:

```
$this->db->select('first_name', 'last_name');
$this->db->from('people');
$this->db->where('id', 449587);
$this->db->order_by('last_name, first_name');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

It’s possible to chain all these conditions together on a single line, but I prefer putting them on separate lines for readability.

In simple word, `get_where` is a luxury to use but `where()` gives you more flexibility to use.

Answer (score 1):

The `get_where` is a combined function -so to speak- of the both `where()` and `get()` functions,

according to the documentation :

> **$this->db->get_where()**
>
> Identical to the above function except that it permits you to add a
>   "where" clause in the second parameter, instead of using the
>   db->where() function

also by take a quick look at the source code of the [`get_where()`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/af5c8960d80a9db362722ca675ffddb2079bbce9/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1534) method you will notice that

```
if ($where !== NULL)
{
    $this->where($where);
}
```

where `$where` is the second parameter of `get_where()` method.

In simple terms, `$this->db->get_where('table name', 'where clause')` is an alias for `$this->db->where('where clause')->get('table name');`